# How do I filter a dataframe so that only certain values show up?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe df, with columns "source, target, weight" , and I need to use a scala (no SQL) command to:

1. Get all weights above 10 and
2. drop all duplicate rows.

For 1, i tried df.filter("weight>=10") but that doesn't work

For 2, i tried df.dropDuplicates(), but that isn't working either

I am using [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) as a reference for the above commands.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by "that does not work"?

Answer (score 3):

you are using `filter` in a wrong way, look at the below snippet to understand

```
import sparkSession.implicits._

val dataframe = Seq(("x", 20, 10), ("y", 30, 20), ("y", 30, 20), ("z", 10, 20)).toDF("source", "target", "weight")

val result1 = dataframe.filter($"weight" > 10)
val result2 = dataframe.filter($"weight" > 10).dropDuplicates()

dataframe.show
result1.show
result2.show
```

and the output is

```
+------+------+------+
|source|target|weight|
+------+------+------+
|     x|    20|    10|
|     y|    30|    20|
|     y|    30|    20|
|     z|    10|    20|
+------+------+------+

+------+------+------+
|source|target|weight|
+------+------+------+
|     y|    30|    20|
|     y|    30|    20|
|     z|    10|    20|
+------+------+------+

+------+------+------+
|source|target|weight|
+------+------+------+
|     y|    30|    20|
|     z|    10|    20|
+------+------+------+
```

Comment: There is nothing with `.filter("weight>=10")`

Comment: But how do I have it reformat the original df? Do I have to do dataframe=dataframe.filter($"weight" > 10).show?